# sortedBy parameter as a variable

Tags: sorting, lambda, collections, kotlin

I have a method which needs to sort a collection in many possible ways. Instead of calling `myCollection.sortedBy` multiple times, I'd like to have the lambda which I'd pass to `sortedBy` in a variable, and later I'd pass that variable to one single call to `sortedBy`. However, I can't figure out the type which that lambda variable should have. Keep in mind that the "sorted-by fields" may have different types (but they're all `Comparable`, obviously).

Here's a simplified version of my problem:

```
data class Person(val name: String, val age: Int)

enum class SortBy {
    NAME, AGE
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val people = listOf(Person("John", 30), Person("Mary", 20))
    val sort = SortBy.NAME

    val comparator = when (sort) {
        SortBy.NAME -> { p: Person -> p.name }
        SortBy.AGE -> { p: Person -> p.age }
    }

    // the line below won't compile
    people.sortedBy(comparator).forEach(::println)
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the two lambdas have very different types, so the type of the variable `comparator` is simply inferred to be `Any`, which is first common supertype. There is no other type (other than `Any?`) which this variable can have if you need to be able to assign either of the lambdas to it.

Then, depending on what you ended up with (either a `(Person) -> Int` or a `(Person) -> String`), the `sortedBy` method would have to somehow infer its type parameter, which again is impossible while handling both cases.

---

However, there's a solution. You can create `Comparator<Person>` instances in the different `when` branches instead which wrap the specific types of whatever the `Person` instances are compared by, with the [`compareBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/compare-by.html) function:

```
val comparator: Comparator<Person> = when (sort) {
    SortBy.NAME -> compareBy { it.name }
    SortBy.AGE -> compareBy { it.age }
}
```

And then use the [`sortedWith`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-with.html) method that takes a `Comparator` instead of a selector lambda:

```
people.sortedWith(comparator).forEach(::println)
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly. I wasn't aware of `compareBy` before.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use property references

```
val people = listOf(Person("John", 30), Person("Mary", 20))
val sort = Person::age
people.sortedBy(sort).forEach(::println)
```

Comment: The point is to make the variable `sort` able to hold `Person::age`, `Person::name`, etc, with different types. That's why my example has that `when` scenario (the real scenario is more complicated than sorting by only one field, hard coded). This solution wouldn't work in that situation.